# Google Earth Engine comment/uncomment shortcut on Mac

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

This is a bit of a weird question, but I recently switched from a PC to a Macbook (with a latin keyboard) and I cannot figure out the shortcut to comment/uncomment text in the Code Editor.

On the PC it used to be <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd>, and according to the Code Editor shortcut menu on Mac it should be <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd>, but doing that does not work. I tried <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>7</kbd> (that's where the forward slash is located on the laptop keyboard), <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>7</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>7</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>7</kbd>, and also tried <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd> using the numeric pad of a bluetooth keyboard, but neither worked. Has anyone figured this out?

For anyone wondering, this is my keyboard setup:

[image]

Comment: please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11443857/shortcut-to-comment-out-a-block-of-code-with-sublime-text (read the comments)

Comment: Yeah like I said Command + / does not work. Neither does Command + Alt + /.

Comment: This might be an issue specific to GEE, but not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit (April 2023):** Now my <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>;</kbd> shortcut stopped working in Chrome as well but I think I found a solution that might work for everyone. I'm in Linux but I think it will also work in Windows and Mac. *Just change your keybord settings from your language/location to English/US* then search which key in your computer match the <kbd>/</kbd> key in the English (US) keyboard then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>key</kbd> in Google Earth Engine editor (and after using GEE, turn back to your original keyboard settings). That solved the problem in Google Chrome and in Firefox as well.

As mentioned, my notebook keyboard (as in the image bellow, with <kbd>;</kbd> in dark gray) was working with the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>;</kbd> shortcut (but it isn't anymore).

[image: My keyboard with ; pressed]

Now if I change the system keyboard to English/US, the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>;</kbd> shortcut starts to work again. And as you can see in the image bellow, the <kbd>;</kbd> in my keyboard is in the same place as the <kbd>/</kbd> in the English keyboard, so the system is receiving a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd>, which is the comment shortcut for Earth Engine. So after changing to the English keyboard, search which key in your keyboard is in the same place as the <kbd>/</kbd> would be in a English keyboard.

[image: English US keyboard with / pressed, in the same place as ; in my keyboard]

**In Linux** (Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS), you can add an English (US) keyboard going to **Settings** -> **Keyboard** -> **+** sign -> **English (United States)** -> **English (US)** -> **Add**. In your top bar will appear a new language button (in my case is **pt** as my language is Portuguese). Click in it and select English (US) to activate it. After using GEE you can easily click in the same button and switch back to your original keyboard (maybe in other OS this change might be a bit more time consuming).

**In Mac**: [this link might help](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/write-in-another-language-on-mac-mchlp1406/mac). Try to change your keyboard to English (US) as made above.

**In Windows**: [this link might help](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/change-your-keyboard-layout-245c49b8-f856-7fd7-2cf5-41e54c66f5b3). Try to change your keyboard to English (US) as made above.

**Edit:** A bit off this Stack Exchange topic, but the same solution seems to apply to other editor webpages, like [Overleaf](https://overleaf.com/) (in case more users fall into this problem).

**Original answer:**

I had a similar problem with Windows and Linux, using a Portuguese Brazilian keyboard. Maybe my solution can help you as well.

For me, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd> didn't work but <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>;</kbd> worked (I don't know the reason but can be related to the keyboard type, as mine is similar to yours). I also found that both shortcuts didn't work in Mozilla Firefox, just in Google Chrome and Opera. I didn't test in Safari, Edge and others. If you are not using Google Chrome and using <kbd>;</kbd> in place of <kbd>/</kbd> don't work, try switching your browser as well.

Please, let me know if it worked.

Comment: No unfortunately it did not work, even though I am using Chrome also. Tried clicking buttons at random too accompanied by either Ctrl or Cmd, which unsurprisingly did not work either, haha.

Comment: Oh no! It's a pity. Looks like we can only wait till Google fixes it, hope it doesn't take too long (more than you already waited).

Comment: @M. Nicolas I made some changes in my answer , maybe now it can help you.

Comment: Wow! Thanks!! It seems you've found the only way that works, it's a shame that we have to change keyboards for it but maybe one day GEE will solve this issue for non-english keyboards. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I also couldn't use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd>, but <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>#</kbd> worked for me.

Comment: Didn't work either, I think because to type # on this keyboard you have to type Option + 3

Answer (score 0):

For me, using windows 10 and a swiss keyboard setup it is

Ctrl + °

That works. No idea why, but I'm glad to have found it.

Comment: I used it and it worked Ctrl + ° That works.

Comment: No luck either :(